# An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I was trying to learn [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) and [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) using [this tutorial](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.no/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html). However, I get an error.

The error thrown is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

Here is the full error trace:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.Configuration
ErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration>
element. (C:\Users\Ankur\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe.config line 11)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_ConnectionStrings()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultInstance()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor()
   at ConsoleApplication1.ChinookContext..ctor()
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Ankur\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs
:line 16
```

Here is the C# code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new ChinookContext()) //error comes on this line
            {
            }
        }
    }

    class ChinookContext : DbContext
    {
    }
}
```

Here is file *App.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description="Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ChinookContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Chinook_Sqlite_AutoIncrementPKs.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Here is file *packages.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.x86" version="1.0.86.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: How did you get the error trace? I need to see one for a similar problem I am having but cannot find it.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Read the message:

> Only one `<configSections>` element allowed per
>    config file and if present must be the first child of the root  `<configuration>` element.

Move the configSections element to the top - just above where system.data is currently.

Comment: Hello, can I ask a question, I have the same setup as in the question and after adding the change you have described I am getting the following error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Data.dll  Additional information: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.

Comment: @Azaryan I don't know; all I can suggest is: *read the full error message* (including any inner-exceptions)

Comment: I also had this problem and the error message does explain the issue, but my configSection WAS the first node under the Configuration element. It turned out that it was a problem in a referenced dll that did not have it as the first node.

Answer (score 4):

Check which version of Entity Framework reference you have in your References and make sure that it matches with your `configSections` node in `Web.config` file. In my case it was pointing to version 5.0.0.0 in my configSections and my reference was 6.0.0.0. I just changed it and it worked...

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `Web.Config` from `Main` folder, not the one in `Views` Folder:

configSections

section `name="entityFramework" type="System.Data. .....,Version=" <strong>5</strong>.0.0.0"..`

<..>

ADJUST THE VERSION OF EntityFramework you have installed, ex. like Version **6**.0.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Check that right version is referenced in your project. E.g. the dll it is complaining about, could be from an older version and that's why there could be a version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when i refereed a library project from a console application, and the library project was using a nuget package which is not refereed in the console application. Referring the same package in the console application helped to resolve this issue.

Seeing the Inner exception can help.

Answer (score -3):

In static class,
if you are getting information from xml or reg, class tries to initialize all properties. therefore, you should control if the config variable is there otherwise properties will not initialize so the class.

**Check xml referance variable is there,
Check reg referance variable is is there,
Make sure you handle if they are not there.**

Comment: What is the relevance of xml and "reg" (what is "reg"?)? What are referance variables? How do you handle them not being there?

Comment: mostly config reads from xml file. If the thing that you are looking for is not in the xml file, class will give you error. Some config files read from reg file. If you read some stuff from reg, you should check that too. Reg means registry