# Program Crashes Without Breakpoint?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oledb

I have a connection to a database, but when I open it, the program crashes.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in System.Transactions.dll

When I have a breakpoint at `con.Open();` and then continue, it works well.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path);
con.Open(); // Here I have the Breakpoint
```

I have no idea what is wrong with my code.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Look at the inner exception

Comment: What CPU mode are you compiling for?

Comment: Just make a try with this- Put a **Thread.Sleep(1)** before your **con.Open()** and see, whether crash is there ?

Comment: Please use a try catch and see what the message is..

Comment: @KevinCrain, He already added that - **An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in System.Transactions.dll**

Comment: Sorry I am yellow blind :)

Comment: See this link it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132698/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-typeinitializationexception-occurred-in