# System.TypeInitializationException' occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am making application in ASP.NET MVC 5 C#.
I am getting exception while trying to access connection string element from web.config file.

> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in
>   WebPortalClient.dll but was not handled in user code

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>  
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="WebPortalClient.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebPortalClient-20140714023603;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="WebPortalClient.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.141;Initial Catalog=Dishkau;User ID=saud;Password=rakeord1"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="99999" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
           <!-- Set the maximum request size to 1GB (the value is in Bytes here) -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />

    </modules>

  <!--<modules>
      <add name="SingleSessionEnforcement" type="SingleSessionEnforcement" />
    </modules>-->
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000">
                </jsonSerialization>
            </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
  <applicationSettings>
    <WebPortalClient.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="UploadServiceUrl" serializeAs="String">
        <value>192.168.1.141:8085/lupload/</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LicenseName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>ARL</value>
      </setting>
    </WebPortalClient.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132698/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-typeinitializationexception-occurred-in) but it was of no help.
Please help me out.

Comment: What is the `.InnerException.Message` of that exception? Without that, we're shooting in the dark. Although to be fair, visibility of the static constructor and/or static field initializers on the offending type would be a good help, too.

Comment: Inner Exception is {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}

Comment: there we go; then ... go check that the SQL server is available; online, available through firewall rules, etc...

Comment: SQL server is running. I have one web service which takes data from db. its working fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution i've found about it:

This exception means that the following  line fails(check for the fitting line in your code):

```
public static string ConString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
```

Make sure that no exception happens here!

Whenever TypeInitializationException is thrown, check all initialization logic of the type you are referring to for the first time in the statement where the exception is thrown.

If it is not working you can use [this post](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/)

Comment: This statement does not throw exception.

Inner exception :  {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}

Comment: did you check that this is the right connection string?

Comment: i edited the answer and attached a link to a post that can help

Comment: Thanks dear. 
I just restarted PC and its fixed automatically.

Comment: The link [TypeInitializationException](https://www.dotnetperls.com/typeinitializationexception) prove helpful to me for understanding and sorting out the issue.