# System.TypeInitializationException occured in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Yesterday I asked a question about why my program was not creating the database as this tutorial http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx states that it should. I got some of the problems fixed, but ended up with another exception being thrown:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Typeinitialiseringsfunktionen for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

So if anyone has any idea why this exception gets thrown, please help :)

Entire Exception detail:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233036 Message=Typeinitialiseringsfunktionen for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' udløste en undtagelse.   Source=EntityFramework   TypeName=System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig   StackTrace:
       ved System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultInstance()
       ved System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection..ctor(DbContext context, String nameOrConnectionString)
       ved System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
       ved ShopEntity.ShopContext..ctor() i C:\Users\Anders\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ShopEntity\ShopEntity\ShopContext.cs:linje 12
       ved ShopEntity.Program.Main() i C:\Users\Anders\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ShopEntity\ShopEntity\Program.cs:linje 17
       ved System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       ved System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       ved Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       ved System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       ved System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       ved System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       ved System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       ved System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: 
       BareMessage='connectionStrings'-element, der ikke er genkendt.
       Filename=C:\Users\Anders\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ShopEntity\ShopEntity\bin\Debug\ShopEntity.vshost.exe.Config
       HResult=-2146232062
       Line=15
       Message='connectionStrings'-element, der ikke er genkendt. (C:\Users\Anders\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ShopEntity\ShopEntity\bin\Debug\ShopEntity.vshost.exe.Config line 15)
       Source=System.Configuration
       StackTrace:
            ved System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
            ved System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
            ved System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
            ved System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
            ved System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
            ved System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
            ved System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
            ved System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
            ved System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()
            ved System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()
       InnerException:
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ShopEntity
{
    class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }


    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShopEntity
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var ctx = new ShopContext())
            {
                User adminUser = new User()
                {
                    Address = "Skejby Vænge 96A",
                    EMailAddress = "anderskloborg@gmail.com",
                    IsAdmin = 1,
                    PassWord = "12345678",
                    UserName = "Anders1234"
                };
                //Product Apple = new Product() { Price = 2, ProductName = "Apple" };
                //Product Melon = new Product() { Price = 10, ProductName = "Melon" };
                //Product Beef = new Product() { Price = 40, ProductName = "Beef" };
                ctx.Users.Add(adminUser);
                //ctx.Products.Add(Apple);
                //ctx.Products.Add(Melon);
                //ctx.Products.Add(Beef);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

            }




                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ShopEntity
{
    class ShopContext: DbContext
    {
        public ShopContext() : base()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }


    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ShopEntity
{
    class User
    {

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string PassWord { get; set; }
        public string EMailAddress { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public byte IsAdmin { get; set; }

    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132698/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-typeinitializationexception-occurred-in)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I only have one <ConfigSections> tag in my appconfig :)

Comment: You have no actual connection string to the database anywhere - it is possible that it is throwing because it cannot work out which db to connect to.

Comment: But where would I find an actual connectionstring when the database hasn't been created yet? I thought I could just name it and then it would create a database with a connectionstring with that name

Comment: @sunero4 I bet it is a duplicate. Please provide the full text of the exception along with the stack trace, as is done in the duplicate question. Also please post your config file.

Comment: @sunero4 - EntityFramework would still not know what the database name should be or on which server to create it - therefore it cannot create an instance of the context.

Comment: I added the exception detail, sorry it looks ugly, didn't know how to format it. 
The thing is that I did this one time before with the examples of classes that the guy in the tutorial uses, and it works without even passing it a connectionstring in the base(), but now that I try with my own class names and stuff it doesn't

Comment: @sunero4 - the stack trace confirms that the error is because there is no connection strings section in the app.config so EntityFramework does not know how to connect to any database.

Comment: Okay, great! So what should I change to make it work? I'm just getting started with both EF and databases in general so I don't really know how to create a connection string before the database is already created

Comment: @sunero4 this is a really basic question, you should be able to locate an existing answer in no time ;)

Comment: @sunero4, see [MSDN Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for some guidance on Connection Strings for Entity Framework